NFC with expo managed workflow
Can I read NFC tags in react native project which are using expo, but I want to have managed workflow because it's simpler. Did someone know how to do this without changing to bare workflow?
How to use NFC tags in managed workflow?

I'm not entirely sure about the solution, but I found a package that claims to support NFC with Expo.
You can check out the Expo NFC Package. Give it a try, and if it works, that's great! If not, feel free to reach out, and we can troubleshoot it together.

I tried this from the wiki of the library.
https://github.com/revtel/react-native-nfc-manager/wiki/Expo-Go
But it didn't work, I didn't know what else to do, so I rewrote the project in bare react native.
At least it was 2 days of work for me.
If you want to create a project in expo with NFC, try first to see if the NFC works and then build the app, don't make the same mistake as me.
